# Exibir próximo id da tabela em um input do formulario

Tags: php, css, mysqli

preciso exibir o proximo numero de id em um input, no caso o formulario seria de uma nova venda, então preciso que apareça num input onde diz o numero da venda atual q sera feita, no caso o próximo numero do id da tabela q é auto incriment

script para busca do proximo id:
.

include_once "configbanco.php";

```
$sql = "select (max(Id) + 1) from venda";
$resultado = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$result = mysqli_fetch_row ($resultado);
$id = $result;
```

formulario que recebera próximo id:

```
        <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-7 mr-3">
        </div>
        <label class=" col-form-label mr-1" ></label>
        <div class="col-sm-1 mr-3">
        </div>
        <label for="idvenda" class=" col-form-label mr-3" >Número da Venda</label>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        <input class="form-control" id="idvenda" name="idvenda" value="<?php echo $id ?>" required  readonly >
        </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
```

no momento esta exibindo "array" como valor no campo input

Comment: esse não é um meio confiável de ser o próximo e depois pode haver uma nova inserção de dados no banco e aí de mudar e então não ser mais válido o número exibido. Não sei se existe algum modo de informar o próximo ID a ser incrementado a menos que somente o usuário faz uso do seu sistema ou com trava de tabela.

Comment: poise mas n tem como ter inserção antes deste formulario nesta tabela... é como em uma ordem de serviço, tera que mostrar o numero da ordem que vc esta abrindo, no caso o proximo id da tabela a ser gerado... no caso meu comando select da resultado no banco mesmo, ele mostra... só preciso que ali ele mostre o resultado o dessa query ...

Comment: Você pode criar um TOKEN para isso, ao invés de usar o ID de registro da TABELA, o que não  é seguro usar o ID como também não pode ter controle com várias sessões fazendo  uso do sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um TOKEN para a ordem de serviço ao invés de usar o ID para isso, o que não é seguro usar o ID como também não pode ter controle com várias sessões fazendo  uso do sistema.

Sugiro uma função para isso:

```
if(!function_exists('numero_unico')){
    function numero_unico( $quantidade=NULL, $prefixo=NULL ){
        $aleatorio = (date('s') + date('i') * 10000);
        $numerounico = time();
        $numerounico1 = ($numerounico.mt_rand(111111,999999));
        $numerounico2 = ($numerounico.mt_rand(111111,999999));
        $numerounico = ($aleatorio.$numerounico.$numerounico1.$numerounico2);
        $numerounico = str_shuffle($numerounico);
        if($quantidade === 0){

        } else{
            $numerounico = substr($numerounico, 0, $quantidade);
        }
        $conta_prefixo = strlen($prefixo);
        if($conta_prefixo >= 1){
            $numerounico = ($prefixo . $numerounico);
        }
        return $numerounico;
    }
}
```

Na função acima existem duas possibilidades, a de gerar um número único com apenas valores numéricos como também criar um valor com um prefixo:

```
$token = numero_unico(12); // Guarda na variável valor numérico de 12 dígitos, ex: 102030405060

$token = numero_unico(12,'TKN'); // Guarda na variável valor numérico de 12 dígitos com prefixo TKN, ex: TKN102030405060
```

Depois você faz uso dele no seu `input`

```
<input class="form-control" id="idvenda" name="idvenda" value="<?php echo $token ?>" required readonly />
```

Comment: ok, obrigado vou verificar

Answer (score -2):

Verifica a variável $id com um var_dump($id).

Acredito que a variável $result e esteja passando um array, então vc pode usar $id = $result[0];

Comment: vou verificar isso, poise, e minha query esta funcionando, pois no banco esta mostrando resultado se eu consultar daquela forma, só precisaria que mostrasse o resultado no input... complicado e parece tão simples kkk